# How to uninstall PostgreSQL installed from .run file?

Tags: uninstall, postgresql

I am a new Ubuntu 12.04 user and I'm using 64bit.

This morning I installed Posgresql 9.2 from the [graphical installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgresql-921-installers-linux32?ls=Crossover&type=Crossover) (not from Ubuntu repository) . Now I want to uninstall it, but I don't know how.

Anyone please show me the way out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installer should have installed also a program called `uninstall-postgresql`. Open a terminal and run

```
sudo uninstall-postgresql
```

This should work. If the shell complains that it cannot find the program (`command not found`), find where it was installed:

```
sudo updatedb
locate uninstall-postgresql
```

and run it with the full path returned by locate.

Comment: i seem to be in a streak of "just a few min too late" today :P

Comment: so here is a +1 for you :-)

Comment: @January: the first command returns "command not found" and the second returns nothing. The situation may be complicated because I tried some other ways to uninstall and re-install. However, there's still Postgresql 9.2 item when I run pgAdmin3.

Comment: If that is the case, you should try to describe, as good as you can, everything that you did. We have no way of knowing what is still on your hard disk; maybe you have removed the uninstaller? Or run the installer again, and then run the uninstaller.

Comment: Since you installed it just today, it is possible locate doesnt know whr it is. can you try `sudo updatedb` and then try the locate again?

Comment: After "sudo updatedb", locate worked and I could uninstall with "sudo /path/to/uninstall-postgresql". Thank you very much for your help, January and Karthik T.

Comment: Cool, I modify my answer to include @KarthikT's suggestion.

Comment: glad to hear it, congrats

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ubuntu!

**Generally**, in such a situation, you would try to find your program in `Software Center` or `Synaptic Package Manager` and then remove from there.

**Specifically** in this case, it appears there is a script somewhr that is made for this purpose. According to [this](http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1437.page) post, there is a `uninstall-postgresql` script that you can run by opening Terminal and typing that in. If that doesnt work, that post has more information that you can go through.

Comment: I opened Synatic, searched for "postgresql" and there were so many items that I don't know what is what. I'll try other ways in your link above. Thanks.

Comment: in such a case i would try to find the most generic one. that tends to be the main or parent package and the rest would be modules or plugins. In your case however it is a special install, so it might be better trying to track down the uninstaller, try my comment on the other answer.